# Ruby How can I use check boxes to change view on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, radio-button

I am using checkboxes and I need to display a different table depending on which button the user selects. Is this even possible with check boxes? Thanks

> index.html.erb
>       
>       
>   <%= check_box_tag("Locations", value = "1", checked = true) %>
>   
>   <%= check_box_tag("List of Favorite Places", value = "2", checked = false) %>
>       
>       
>       <% if value = "1" %>
>        
>            *Show table 1* 
>       
>      <% else value = "2" %>
>       
>           *Show table 2*

Comment: Everything is possible! You need javascript for this. You'll need to send ajax request and populate another element with the response. `pjax` gem might be handy here. Alternatively you can have both tables in the source and have your js hiding one and showing the otherwhen radio button is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is possible, but you can't achieve it in the way you envision. Templates (ERb, HAML, Slim, etc.) are used to build the page on the server side during the request-response cycle. After being built, the page is then sent to the client (browser) for the user to interact with. Once it is in the client, you need to use JavaScript to manipulate the page dynamically. For example, using JQuery, you might do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table1 = $('#table1');
    $('#my-checkbox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            table1.show();
        else {
            table1.hide();
        }
    });  
});
```

The details are up to you, of course.